# Use Redis Win64 port in PROD environment

Tags: c#, redis, production

I have been playing with Redis win64 port with ServiceStack.Redis client (in C#) since couple of weeks now, and it has admired me alot. 
The significant gain in performance I have seen using Redis has made me to think of moving my web application caching to Redis. 
So far I haven't faced any issue and my web app is running smoothly using Redis for caching with visible performance gain. Response time has been greatly reduced and my app testers are pretty happy with that.

**Now I'm planning to go further ahead and move it to PRODUCTION environment. Before that I'd like to know that:**

- If it is GOOD to GO with Redis win64 port in PROD environment OR still there are some question marks in doing so.
- Are there any recommendations if I opt to go in PROD?
- How Redis is used at StackExchange?

Looking forward to some good feedback.

Comment: At SE we use redis on Ubuntu server, not windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [official word from the developers](http://redis.io/topics/introduction) sounds like you're a bit on your own;

***There is no official support for Windows builds, although you may have some options.***

As to an official supported Windows version, you seem to be out of luck, but for future reference, [Microsoft is working on a Windows version](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/Redis#readme) but it's currently at the prototype stage and there are [other options](https://github.com/dmajkic/redis#readme) but they seem to currently reference back to Microsofts prototype port for coming official support.

Your best supported option would seem to - like all production deployments I know of - be to run Redis on linux for now.